# MySQL Query returning empty result

Tags: mysql, go, go-gin, gorp

I have a simple `SELECT` statement which calls all of the columns in my `coupon` table by `who_added`.

**code:**

```
func CouponByUserID(c *gin.Context) {
    fmt.Println("CouponByUserID()")
    lCoupon := []model.Coupon{}
    whoAdded := c.PostForm("whoAdded")
    fmt.Println("whoAdded: " + whoAdded)

    var sqlSel = ""
    sqlSel = sqlSel + " SELECT * FROM coupon WHERE who_added = ? "

    fmt.Println("sqlSel")
    fmt.Println(sqlSel)
    _, err := dbmap.Select(&lCoupon, sqlSel, whoAdded)

    if err == nil || lCoupon != nil {
        fmt.Println("got result")
        fmt.Println(lCoupon)
        c.Header("Content-Type", "application/json")
        c.JSON(http.StatusOK, lCoupon)
    } else {
        fmt.Println("coupon not found")
        c.JSON(404, gin.H{"error": "coupon not found"})
    }
}
```

**Coupon Model:**

```
type Coupon struct {
    CouponID          int64   `db:"coupon_id, primarykey, autoincrement"`
    CouponName        string  `db:"coupon_name,omitempty"`
    CouponCode        string  `db:"coupon_code,omitempty"`
    Description       string  `db:"description,omitempty"`
    Status            string  `db:"status,omitempty"`
    CampaignStart     int64   `db:"campaign_start,omitempty"`
    CampaignEnd       int64   `db:"campaign_end,omitempty"`
    SourceType        string  `db:"source_type,omitempty"`
    Preview           string  `db:"preview,omitempty"`
    CouponFormat      string  `db:"coupon_format,omitempty"`
    PreviewType       string  `db:"preview_format,omitempty"`
    Display           string  `db:"display,omitempty"`
    DisplayType       string  `db:"display_format,omitempty"`
    Width             float64 `db:"width,omitempty"`
    Height            float64 `db:"height,omitempty"`
    WhoAdded          int     `db:"who_added,omitempty"`
    WhenAdded         int     `db:"when_added,omitempty"`
    WhoUpdated        int     `db:"who_updated,omitempty"`
    WhenUpdated       int     `db:"when_updated,omitempty"`
    TermsAndCondition string  `db:"terms_and_condition,omitempty"`
    CouponLocation    string  `db:"coupon_location,omitempty"`
    BusID             string  `db:"bus_id,omitempty"`
    ImgCoupon         string  `db:"img_coupon,omitempty"`
}
```

**Result:**
As you can see here it's empty even if my table has data.

[image: postman]

**Problem:** Data on my table is not showing in the result.

I tried to query the same statement on MySQL workbench and it's work just fine.

Where did I go wrong?

Comment: are you certain your app is connected to the correct db and that that db's tables do contain the data that you expect the api to return?

Comment: @mkopriva yes, I have other more queries in gin gonic and it works just fine.

Comment: This is the only query that doesn't fetch data, I did double-check the model to make sure that the column in the table on MySQL is the same.

Comment: Try looking at the actual SQL and args sent to the server by gorp with: https://github.com/go-gorp/gorp#sql-logging. And if that doesn't make the problem clear consider sharing that log output with us here.

Comment: Note that you should not consider a non-nil `err` value as always meaning no-rows. An error could have been returned for a multitude of other reasons and yet you're treating all of them as "no rows found", that is just incorrect.

Comment: In your `coupon` table, are there records with `who_added = 9`?

Comment: @mkopriva yes, if you want I'll show you the whole table.

Comment: @mkopriva I did it in MySQL workbench `SELECT * FROM coupon WHERE who_added = 9` and it shows all the row

Comment: Have you checked the type of variable whoAdded, is it int while inserting in query? Please check the type. Also please first run the query ("SELECT * FROM coupon WHERE who_added = 9") through code directly instead of reading value from request.

Comment: @xs2tarunkukreja I hardcoded the `SELECT * FROM coupon WHERE who_added = 9` on the statement the result is still empty.

Comment: Not sure whether it will work for you or not... But if condition to check error is not appearing correct to me "err == nil || lCoupon != nil". Even if err is not nil even then if block can execute. Ideally if err is not nil then we should ignore other return value.

Comment: @AgentRed try to "dumb down" the handler to see if the *connection* can retrieve any rows at all. That is, try `select * from coupon` and use it with the std lib instead of `gorp`, i.e. [`dbmap.Db`](https://godoc.org/github.com/go-gorp/gorp#DbMap.Db).[`Query`](https://godoc.org/database/sql#DB.Query) then see if it found anything by iterating over the returned `rows` value. If that you get 0 rows then you know that your table is empty. If it returns some rows then progressively work your way back to the original version of the code to zoom in on the possible cause.